# Windows Phone 7 Listbox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i) returns null?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7.1

I am trying to get a Listbox Item by below code. Basically what i am trying to do is create a tempdatelist and then set the itemsource of Listbox to tempdatelist.

```
if (App.Saveholidayplan[App.selectedlistindex].travel.Count > 0)       
    foreach (var dictobj in App.Saveholidayplan[App.selectedlistindex].travel[0].DummyRepository)                
        tempdatelist.Add(dictobj.Key);


lst_mainlist.ItemsSource = tempdatelist; 

ListBoxItem item = this.lst_mainlist.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i) as ListBoxItem; 

//* item is alway null, that is the problem
if(item != null)
```

But in the above code item retuns null.

When i check Online some suggested to call `ItemContainerGenerator.StatusChanged` event.

But i am not able to find this event in WP7?
Is there a StatusChanged event in WP7 and if not what is the alternative?

Comment: Show more of youre code so we can see the context of the snippets you've included

Comment: edited my question with context of code

Comment: what are you going to do with `item` once you get it?  I'm not quite sure why you're messing with ItemContainerGenerator here.

Comment: i am binding the listboxitems dynamically and on click of save button in OnNavigatedTo Event i am trying to get the item in the Listbox and using the VisualTree getting the value with inthe control. Please see the code below                              string setPlace = FindFirstElementInVisualTree(item, "txtPlace");  // Adding places to list

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too. The solution is to wait for the UI to render by using the dispatcher, like this:

```
this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
{
   ListBoxItem item = this.lst_mainlist.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i);
   //...
});
```